# How to flag and report user in firebase firestore database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have application which have multiple users, one of the major thing left is to block and report users in firebase.
I am trying to look for the solution for the same by googling for it, but till now not any particular success.

I would like to know how I can achieve that. Please guide me for that,

and how the firestore security rules should be to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach is to have a collection that contains the blocked users, with one document for each blocked user and with the ID of that document being the UID of that user.

With that structure in place, your security rules can check for the existence of such a document and then block the user.

There's a great example of this in the blog post [7 tips on Firebase security rules and the Admin SDK](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/firebase-security-rules-admin-sdk-tips.html) (it's tip 7). The rules from there:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isBlackListed() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/blacklist/$(request.auth.uid))
    }

    // Collections are closed for reads and writes by default. This match block
    // is included for clarity.
    match /blacklist/{entry} {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write: if false;
    }

    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow write: if !isBlackListed()
    }
  }
}
```